# How do I download Outlook e-mails from the last 15 days only?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

As I only want to download emails from past 15 days, I don't need the emails prior to that on this Outlook. It is okay if they remain on the server. I tried to follow the below steps:

File account settings -> account settings From the "account settings" window select the email account Click Change

Under Offline settings move the slider to the far right till it reads "all" Click Next Restart outlook

But I am not able to find the offline settings, I using Windows 10 with Outlook provided by my Office 365 (O365) subscription.

Comment: After you click **Change** drag the the slider to the left, it will give you the option to cache less mail on your system.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you running?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, you can go to:

- File > Account Settings > Account Settings...
- Select your e-mail box
- Click on Change
- Make sure Use Cached Exchange Mode is checked on
- Drag the slider all the way to the left to 1 month

[image: Outlook 2013 Cached Exchange Mode]